# Subgroup of$\mathbb{Z}$ and finite subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

In class, we described a subgroup as follow :

A subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ is called a subgroup if it is nonempty, and the sum and difference of any two of its members is also a member.

I would like to find the "unique finite subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. I think it is $S=\{0\}$ but I am not sure $S$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ in this case.

Comment: (1) Yes it is $\{0\}$. (2) Yes it is a subgroup - it's nonempty, and both of $0+0$ and $0-0$ are $0$. (3) Do you know why it's the only one?

Comment: On a side note, you don't need sums, just differences for the subset to be a subgroup.  (You can derive sums from differences.)

Answer (score 2):

If a such a subgroup is not $\{0\}$, it contains $n\neq 0$, for every $p$ integer, $pn$ is in the group and the cardinal of $\{pn, p\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is infinite.